# Checkboxes visible to all users

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, global, state

Just a quick question here. I'm currently working on an interactive slideshow element, and have found a need for a checkbox or button to show an item in said slideshow as "taken" by a user. Are there any ways to code checkboxes so that they will display a 'checked' or 'unchecked' state no matter where they're viewed from? (ie; if I check the box, I want for someone else, on another computer to be able to see the box is checked.)

Any ideas?

Comment: Store the data in database and show to the users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to save the state of the checkbox in your server database, you can make a ajax call to the server with the state of the checkbox like this:

```
if ($('#yourcheckbox1').is(':checked')) {
   $.get("serverfile.php", {state: "enabled", id : "1"}, function(d){
          //response received from the server
   });

}else{
   $.get("serverfile.php", {state: "disabled", id : "1"}, function(d){
          //response received from the server
   });

 }
```

You can do this for all the checkboxes, the id is to tell the server which checkbox you are talking about.
On the server side you do this:

```
$id = $_GET["id"];
$state = $_GET["state"];
//save these values to the database
```

Now you can use these values to display on the presentation for all the users.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

you need to persist the state in the server and then sent it to the clients

Answer (score -1):

I have't understand your question but i can give you code that will help you to checkbox make checked or unchecked.

**Checked Code:**

```
$("checkebox").each(function() {
       $(this).attr("checked", true);
   });
```

**UnChecked Code:**

```
$("checkebox").each(function() {
      $(this).attr("checked", false);
   });
```

Thanks